# Insert embed code only in place of urls that are not in href

Tags: php, regex, drupal, str-replace

I am customizing a module on a drupal 8 website, where certain vimeo or youtube urls are converted into embedded iframe videos. The module itself works great, however a problem arises when there's a tag

`<a href="https://vimeo.com/videoid">Some text</a>.`

A post's body might look somewhat like this:

```
    https://vimeo.com/id1   //this line should get replaced with embed code by module

    <a href="https://vimeo.com/id1"> Check out this video </a> //here, anything that is in href="" should not be replaced
on <a href="https://vimeo.com"> Vimeo </a>
```

In this whole post body, the module matches a url (https://vimeo.com/id1) and then uses str_replace() to replace each url with the generated embed code.

```
$embed_code = $this->convertVimeoUrlToEmbedCode($url);
$return['text'] = str_replace($url, $embed_code, $return['text']);
```

So far what I tried to do was:

- Put a placeholder text in place of the url in the href tag, then replace all urls with the embed code, then put the url back into the placeholder.
- Remove all urls from the text that are in between quotation marks (fixed half of the problem)

In essence, what I'm looking for is for a clean way of replacing the $urls with the embed code while ignoring the $urls that are in quotes or printed in any other way in html tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer would involve using a parser.
For a more hacky solution you could use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` in a regular expression, such as

```
<a[^>]*>[^<]*</a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|https?:\S+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dk1Nb0/1/).

Comment: This seems to work. However in some cases where the post body has more than one video url like that, every url get's replaced by the same embedded code. In this regex code should I somehow replace the https?: part with the $url?

Comment: I changed https?:\S+ part to the url and it works. I guess it's not the cleanest solution, but oh well

Comment: @MantasBagdonas: This won't work with nested links (use a parser here) or `<`/`>` anywhere in the anchor text / attribute.

Comment: Sorry, could you point me to some kind of sources regarding the parser thing? As I'm not quite sure what you're suggesting and I don't really know what to look for